# Python How to match all text between two strings in multiline

Tags: python, regex, multiline

I'm having a bit of trouble getting a Python regex to work when matching against text that spans multiple lines.
The example text is ('\n' is a newline)

```
speakerC：SHAKSDHKWJHFKJWHFKJWFJ\n
speakerA：SHAKSDHKWJHFKJWHFKJWFJ\n
speakerA：Let's beginning to do some thing.\n ----> I want to capture from here
[there may have a variable number of lines here]\n
(voting)
listA：\n
listB：JIJFEOPFOJEWFJ\n
listC：KFOEKOFKWPKEPW\n
listD：JIJFEOPFOJEWFJ\n
JIOFJOWEJ\n
listE：KFOEKOFKWPKEPW\n
votA:\n
[there may have a variable number of lines here or empty]\n
votB:\n
[there may have a variable number of lines here or empty]\n
votC:\n
[there may have a variable number of lines here or empty]\n
(repeat the above a few hundred times)
```

I want to capture all of speakerA until the next speakerA.
However, I only can capture :

```
speakerA：Let's beginning to do some thing.\n.
[there may have a variable number of lines here]\n
(voting)
```

here is pattern:
`pattern = re.compile(r'(^speakerA：.*\n(.*\n)?^（voting）)', re.MULTILINE)`

`edit`

```
speakerC：SHAKSDHKWJHFKJWHFKJWFJ\n
speakerA：SHAKSDHKWJHFKJWHFKJWFJ\n
speakerA: lets beginning to vote\n
[there may have a variable number of lines here that I need it]
(voting)
speakerA: the line that I need it.\n
[there may have a variable number of lines here that I need it]
speakerA: the line that I need it.\n
[there may have a variable number of lines here that I need it]
listA：\n
listB：JIJFEOPFOJEWFJ\n
listC：KFOEKOFKWPKEPW\n
listD：JIJFEOPFOJEWFJ\n
JIOFJOWEJ\n
listE：KFOEKOFKWPKEPW\n
votA:\n
[there may have a variable number of lines here or empty]\n
votB:\n
[there may have a variable number of lines here or empty]\n
votC:\n
[there may have a variable number of lines here or empty]\n
(repeat the above a few hundred times)
```

it will have some key words can help to identify in this line

`speakerA: lets beginning to vote\n`

such as go to vote, have voting and beginning to vote.

Therefore, I want to capture the block from
`speakerA: lets beginning to vote\n` to
`votC:\n [there may have a variable number of lines here or empty]\n`

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Your regex contains "(voting)" (matching plain parentheses requires escaping them like `\(`, `\)` by the way) but you mention "until votC"?

Comment: Thanks. I will add `\(` in my code. Yes, I want to capture containing in `votC:\n
[there may have a variable number of lines here or empty]\n`

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'(?sm)^speakerA[：:].*?(?=^speakerA|\Z)', text)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for replying. may I ask what is `(?sm)` meaning and could you tell why do not use `\n` in pattern and you can find the new line string

Comment: That is an inline modifier. `s`  stands for `re.S` / `re.DOTALL` that allows `.` match newlines that `.` does not match by default. So, does it work?

Comment: ＠WiktorStribiżew I see. It almost works. however, it has some wrong capture. I will edit again and make it more specificity, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify last matching position like this:
`.*?speakerA`

This means match until the first speakerA pattern.

```
import re


text = """
speakerC：SHAKSDHKWJHFKJWHFKJWFJ\n
speakerA：SHAKSDHKWJHFKJWHFKJWFJ\n
speakerA：Let's beginning to do some thing.\n ----> I want to capture from here
[there may have a variable number of lines here]\n
(voting)
listA：\n
listB：JIJFEOPFOJEWFJ\n
listC：KFOEKOFKWPKEPW\n
listD：JIJFEOPFOJEWFJ\n
JIOFJOWEJ\n
listE：KFOEKOFKWPKEPW\n
votA:\n
[there may have a variable number of lines here or empty]\n
votB:\n
[there may have a variable number of lines here or empty]\n
votC:\n
[there may have a variable number of lines here or empty]\n
(repeat the above a few hundred times)
"""

compiled_regex = re.compile(r'speakerA：(Let\'s beginning to do some.*?\(voting\).*?)speakerA：', re.DOTALL)

match = compiled_regex.findall(text)
print(match)
```

Prints:

```
["Let's beginning to do some thing.\n ----> I want to capture from here\n[there may have a variable number of lines here]\n\n(voting)\nlistA：\n\nlistB：JIJFEOPFOJEWFJ\n\nlistC：KFOEKOFKWPKEPW\n\nlistD：JIJFEOPFOJEWFJ\n\nJIOFJOWEJ\n\nlistE：KFOEKOFKWPKEPW\n\nvotA:\n\n[there may have a variable number of lines here or empty]\n\nvotB:\n\n[there may have a variable number of lines here or empty]\n\nvotC:\n\n[there may have a variable number of lines here or empty]\n\n(repeat the above a few hundred times)\n"]
```

EDIT:

```
compiled_regex = re.compile(r'speakerA：(Let\'s beginning to do some.*?\(voting\).*?)speakerA：', re.DOTALL)
```

UPDATE ( OP chaged match string )

```
compiled_regex = re.compile(r'speakerA: lets beginning to vote(.*?)votC:', re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: excuse me, I made a mistake. It's not until votC, it's until the next speakerA. I edited my question

Comment: No problem, I edited my answer too. It's the same idea. You need to specify your last pattern, now speakerA instead of votC. This solution captured lines between two speakerA, and one of them can starts with a text like : Let's beginning to do something.

Comment: thanks for replying. Since I edited the problem, could you help me

Comment: @matsuri I've already changed my answer according to your edit. Please check it again.

Comment: i also edited some lines in the string. it was not original string. thanks

Comment: Okay now It's matching all lines between ```speakerA: lets beginning to vote``` to ```votC``` . You can move parentheses to capture a wider interval.

Comment: Is this fix your problem @matsuri